# BUG the marker change the color when touch it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-activity, location

> The marker when loading from fragment, loading a color, but when clicked, it changes color, and I have no color change when I click on the marker. Any suggestions to fix it? because it is only in the view that changes, internally if the state logic is fine; the marker should actually be green, but it turns orange.

[bug in marker, must be green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJh6.png)

[change color when touch it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MZPm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set marker in this way hope it help

```
      //place marker where user just clicked
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("You are here!!!")
                .draggable(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));                 
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
```